# 14.04: menus no longer visible in the Unity panel

Tags: unity, 14.04, panel

I ran the updates on Ubuntu 14.04 this morning and now the programme menus are no longer visible in the panel. In this image the mouse is over the panel but no menu are shown:

[image]

I can still access the menus with HUD but I do not think this how Unity is supposed to work. Which package updates could have caused this change in behaviour?

**Update I**: After turning the system on this morning the panel is back to normal; whatever caused this strange behaviour is probably not related to a corrupted package.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do

```
sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt --reinstall
```

and reboot. It could help, if one of the packages are broken for some reason.

It's also possible, that the menus are configured not to show up in the top panel, but in the title bar of the window, that has focus.
You can check the "show menus for a window"-option in *System Settings -> Appearance -> Behaviour* to be in the menu bar or in the windows title bar.

Comment: Hi Belfry, this morning the panel is back to normal when started up the system; I did not update or re-installed any packages. This issue is probably not caused by a broken package.